# Get list of message attachments without downloading whole message

Tags: gmail-api

I want a way to get a list of the attachments for a Message without having to download the whole message.

With "Users.messages: get" we can set the fields to be returned but we can only choose "Payload" which will return the whole payload for the message

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get#try-it

I only want a list of the attachments so that the user can select which attachment to go and fetch.

Is there a more efficient way to do this??

Thanks for your help,

Paul C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no there is not currently.  That said, doing a get?format=FULL should be pretty efficient and not that large of a response (few hundred KB)--it won't typically return any body parts that are very large so it's mostly just metadata.  Typically people don't want just a list of attachments but also metadata about those attachments (filename, size, type, disposition, where they are in the MIME tree since a top-level attachment may not make sense to surface the same way as an attachment inside a .eml attachment, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the answer - using Gmail gadgets users often choose an attachment from an email to save to an external database such as a CRM.  We need to present them with a list to select from so need to pull the list as efficiently as possible.  As you state FORMAT=FULL will still be a lot more efficient than loading the whole message.